# Problems with locating ArrayAdapter creation

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-debug

this is the result of the Logcat that I'm currently getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  446):   Force finishing activity com.centervue.gsd/.activity.GsdMonitorActivity
```

Is there a way to understand what ArrayAdapter is crashing? Unfortunately the project is really big, concurrent and I have no idea of which one is crashing (and debugger doesn't help a lot) :(

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, the problem was in a DialogFragment where the previous coder has let a "null" case as description... so the String array that goes inside the ArrayAdapter was like "[null]" causing the crash.

Resolving the default case with null into a more descriptive (and not null) message, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The resource in `ArrayAdapter.java:394` is null. This is because you try to call something that is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the [ArrayAdapter](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L394) it seems to me that you didn't specify a correct textViewId or a wrong item layout. If you would update your question with the code where you initialize the adapter I could be more specific.

Comment: the problem is that I have a lot of ArrayAdapters and I don't know which one crashes.. is there a way to locate the chosen one?

Comment: Not really you can narrow it down by just posting those of your current active activity/fragment